# How to access custom cabal flags inside Setup.hs

Tags: haskell, cabal

I would like to use a custom cabal flag to enable some logic inside my `Setup.hs`, i.e. if I run `cabal install -ffoo` I would like to see that `foo` was enabled in my hook. I am, for reference, using the `Custom` build-type.

I expected I might find this in the `configConfigurationsFlags` field of the `ConfigFlags`, but that field is invariably empty when I run cabal. Are the values of custom flags stored elsewhere, or should I be taking a completely different approach here?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out using `configConfigurationsFlags` does work, I had just accidentally nested my `Flag` block inside an `Executable`. Moving the `Flag` to the top-level of the cabal file fixes everything.